# SQL Server 2012 - Why would changing the compatibility mode affect parallelism in a query?

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-performance

We changed the compatibility mode from 100 (2008) to 110 (2012) on a 2012 Enterprise SQL server last week.

Since then we have found that the performance on a stored procedure has nose dived from 18 minutes to 48 hours (before we killed it).

I changed the compatibility mode back to 100 and the sproc runs in 18 mins again. Comparing plans from before and after, the 110 version has parallelism at every step of the way, the 100 version has none whatsoever. Other stored procedures (about 50) have been running at the normal speed.

This is totally new ground for me, why would changing the compatibility mode from 100 to 110 cause a huge increase in parallelism on just one stored procedure?

Comment: Did you check the execution plan? Before and after changing the compatibility mode? are there significant differences?

Comment: It looks quite similar in terms of operations, but the before (110) version has parallelism affecting almost every operator, the after (100) version has no parallelism at all.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question, addding the OPTION (MAXDOP 1) clause to the offending query will remove the paralleism. You can then at least run at the higher compatibility level.

Comment: can you post both plans?

Answer (score 0):

Changing to higher compatibility level helps sql engine to pick plans as per the latest improvement. So changing the compatibility level is not the main reason for your query slowness.  You should use query hint *OPTION(MAXDOP n)* to find the RCA.

Check the query plan before and after changing the compatibility level. After changing compatibility level check it's plan on MAXDOP 1 by using query hint and then check the plan with MAXDOP n, where n is >1(depends on server hardware).

And don't forget to analyse the query plan with changed compatibility level.